# Retrieving Data From JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, json, console

I'm very new to JSON, so please don't scald me. I'm trying to find a way to retrieve information from this bit of data, but I'm having zero luck.

```
var services = [ "Hernia Repair", "Hip Replacement" ... ];

var places = {
  "place": [
      {
        "name": "The Whittington Hospital",        
        "service": [
          "Hernia Repair",
            {
              "ratings": [
                { "name": "John Doe", "score": 4, "review": "Some text here." },
                { "name": "Jane Doe", "score": 5, "review": "Some more text." }
              ]
            }
            ...
          ]
      },
  ]
};
```

I'm trying to grab the name of the `service` and it's `ratings`'s `name` and `score` and I've been trying to output it to the console like this:

```
places.place[0].service.ratings.name
places.place[0].service.ratings.score
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. If anyone could lend a hand to explain if my nesting is correct or if I'm retrieving them in the correct way.

Any help with this is appreciated.

P.S. Is there also a way to elegantly link the "Hernia Repair" string in the `services` array to the "Hernia Repair" string in the `place` object?

Comment: Please note that your problem has nothing to do with JSON at all! You are working with JavaScript arrays and objects, not with JSON.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "link" in your PS..?

Comment: I am a bit annoyed this has been closed as a duplicate, because 50% of the problem here is not explained in that answer: http://jsfiddle.net/W5yY9/1/

Comment: @SteveFenton Thanks for this! But is there an elegant way to have more than one `service` without repeating the `service` object over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

Service is a list, and ratings is a list, so this should do it:

```
places.place[0].service[1].ratings[0].name
```